# SQL Server 2008 Indexed View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, schema

I am attempting to add `schemabinding` to a view in SQL Server 2008, but I am getting an error of

> Syntax 'Openrowset/Openquery/Opendatasource' is not allowed in schema-bound objects.

I am using `Openquery` because I am querying a linked server and this is the way I must query it.  Is there a workaround for this?

This was the syntax I tried with my view

```
Create View dbo.Test
With Schemabinding
As

  Select * FROM OPENQUERY(191.183.18.101, 'Select * from ls1prod.hrinfo')

Go
```

Comment: Use transactional replication instead? Or maybe a scheduled SSIS package

Comment: @JamesZ - transactional replication?

Comment: Transactional replication is one way to copy a replica of a table to another server, see for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) is pretty clear about what's allowed, and what's not allowed.

Specifically:

> ROWSET functions (OPENDATASOURCE, OPENQUERY, OPENROWSET, AND OPENXML)

There's no 'workaround' because it's not allowed.